# displaying image in text box

Tags: html

i have a textbox for search. how to display image in textbox..eg: searchbox available on most of the websites with search image inside it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use css to do this

Create a style like below in your css

```
.tbl1 {
    background:#FFFFFF url(images/search.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
    padding:4px 4px 4px 22px;
    height:18px;
}
```

and use that class to the text box

```
<input type="text" name="smaple" class="tbl1">
```

Comment: Nice, +1. But class name doesn't match. It should be `tbl1` in style definition too.

Comment: @mudassir Thanks for notifying that... I changed that now in my answer :)