# Using an image as an input text

Tags: html, css, input

Maybe this is an easy question, but I have been searching it for a long time and no luck. 
I simply need to use an image as an input `type=text`, instead of using the white box like normal. I tried to use `background-image`, but then the white is still there, only it has a background image. I don't need the white box. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you explain your question more clearly please

Comment: How can it be a "text" input without the user being able to add text? If it is just an image, where do they type?

Comment: So you want a text box to have a background of an image instead of plain white?

Comment: possible duplicate of [displaying image in text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496372/displaying-image-in-text-box)

Comment: I have just tried and setting a background image, and `border:none` makes the trick actually, what browser are you using to view it? or have you got an example of what you want? because maybe we are missing the point

Comment: White box - do you mean the border around the text input? if so, you can remove the border by using `border:0 none;`

Comment: @WreithKassan I want to use a pattern box as an input text, instead of white box.

Comment: Please post your current `HTML` and `CSS`

Comment: @stackErr no, not background image, because if I used background image, the white box would be still there

Comment: @catwoman instead of `background-image` try `background` in your CSS.

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/C7xyB/??

Comment: @catwoman Please provide a screenshot of the white box that you mean if you use a background-image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

**HTML**

```
<label for="test">Label here</label> 
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" placeholder="placeholder text" />
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=text] {
    background:url(http://placekitten.com/200/200) no-repeat 0 0; 
    border:0 none; 
    padding:4px 10px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VS26J/1/)**

Comment: thanks! I just have to add the background color to transparent. thanks!

Comment: +1 U was messing with the fiddle, and the issue was that you had 4px 4px at the end of the image url, which gave you a margin. By making it 0 0, Nick R made it fill the space.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

http://jsfiddle.net/HU8EE/

HTML

```
<div class="image">Text text text text text text text</div>
```

CSS

```
.image {
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background-image:url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-HX2iaDPwkhs/T6IEBoiufuI/AAAAAAAAAyQ/dtC9Sr268_k/s1600/doodle-525-cloud.jpg);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately no. I need to use an image as an input text

Comment: What does that even mean? you can't just type on an image, you need create something to type over it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this may be a solution. Applying a background image to a text input field: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5u3Pb/)

html:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="10" class="input">default text</textarea>
```

css:

```
.input {
  background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/10x10);
}
```